# How to return a single boost::range or two joined boost::ranges from a function

Tags: c++, boost

I want to write a function that returns either a range that represents two containers, or a range for a single container. The goal is to abstract that in an iteration:

```
const auto range = getRange(...);
for (const auto& object : range) {
   ...
}
```

I thought about using `boost::range::join` this way:

```
auto getRange(...) {
    if (...) {
        return boost::range::join(container1, container2);
    } else {
        return boost::make_iterator_range(container3);
    }
}
```

But it does not compile. Probably I'm not using the correct type here. How can I declare a function that returns a common type that could be iterated uniformly independently of if it represents one or two containers?